# devise_ldap_authenticatable Net::BER::BerError exception after 0.4.9 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ldap, devise

I've upgraded devise_ldap_authenticatable gem from 0.4.6 to the latest version (0.4.9) my previously working LDAP authentication now throws the following exception when I try and authenticate:

> Net::BER::BerError in Devise::SessionsController#create
>
> Unsupported object type: id=139

The following is output in the terminal:

> Started POST "/d/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-11 11:58:45
>   +0100   Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"T+ttL/6YPK1A/HE4XRukI7SKHDTVr553/hOD+5UyYUk=",
>   "user"=>{"username"=>"admin", "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
>   "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}   SQL (0.4ms)   SELECT name 
>   FROM sqlite_master  WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name =
>   'sqlite_sequence'
>
> User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE
>   "users"."username" = 'admin' LIMIT 1   LDAP: LDAP search: uid=admin
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 659ms
>
> Net::BER::BerError (Unsupported object type: id=139):

If I downgrade the gem back to the old version it all springs back in to life (strictly I have to comment out "config.sign_out_via = :delete" in devise.rb too)

FWIW I'm using the following gems/versions:

- Using rails (3.0.9)
- Using devise (1.4.2)
- Using net-ldap (0.2.2)
- Using devise_ldap_authenticatable (0.4.9)

If anyone knows what's happening or can suggest what I can look at to debug this it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much digging I've tracked the problem down to the net-ldap library vers 0.2.2.
I've forked devise_ldap_authenticatable to create a version with the previous version of net-ldap (0.1.1) as the dependency.

You can use my fork if you *really* want but I'll not be maintaining it - it's just a temporary measure until:

a) The net-ldap library is fixed

b) I get time to dig in to the problem in more depth and come up with a better fix

My fork is available at: https://github.com/ashleytowers/devise_ldap_authenticatable

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use old net-ldap?

```
gem install -V net-ldap -v 0.1.1
```

I use net-ldap version 0.1.1 and it works for ruby 1.9

Answer (score 0):

[My fork](https://github.com/prathe/devise_ldap_authenticatable) uses version 0.2.2 of net-ldap (But with a [fix](https://github.com/prathe/ruby-net-ldap/commit/05640940bca2f7a7005cb651ac8e72d64db866e4))

I've release it as a gem. You can use it in your Gemfile

```
gem "prathe_devise_ldap_authenticatable", :require => 'devise_ldap_authenticatable'
```